# How can I get child categories from an array of parent categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 3 WordPress parent categories and I need to create an array containing all child categories from their 3 parents. Is it possible, how can I do this?

Let's suppose:

**parent_cat_number_50 (ID 50)**

- child cat_of_31 (ID 51)
- child cat_of_31 (ID 52)
- child cat_of_31 (ID 53)

**parent_cat_number_70 (ID 70)**

- child cat_of_70 (ID 71)
- child cat_of_70 (ID 72)
- child cat_of_70 (ID 73)

**parent_cat_number_70 (ID 90)**

- child cat_of_90 (ID 91)
- child cat_of_90 (ID 92)
- child cat_of_90 (ID 93)

The array should be: array(51,52,53,71,72,73,91,92,93)

Comment: Do you want to get child categories id from parent categories id?

Comment: Yes, I want to get an array with all child categories of it's parents.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`get_term_children`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children) functions.

```
$term_id = 10; // YOUR PARENT TERM ID
$taxonomy_name = 'products'; // YOUR TAXONOMY NAME
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

echo "<pre>";
print_r($termchildren);
echo "</pre>";
```

OR

You can use this [`_get_term_hierarchy`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_get_term_hierarchy) function.

```
$taxonomy = "category";   // YOUR TAXONOMY NAME
$hierarchy = _get_term_hierarchy($taxonomy);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($hierarchy);
echo "</pre>";
```

Would you please try above code? I think it's helpful for you.

Comment: none of these codes works as expected. I need an array of child categories from multiple parents